# Battlepoint bonus - how does it work?

Tags: dota-2

If **battlepoint bonus** says it is for 2 hours, does it mean it gathers the points exactly in 2 hours of play time, or is it so that I receive bonus for the normal battle point amount even if I activate the booster 10 seconds before I win a match?

Answer (score 1):

It only counts the actual game time the booster was active. So if you enable it 10 seconds before and that 10 seconds is 0.1% of the total match time you will get a bonus equal to 0.1% of that match. Likewise if the booster wears off it only counts for the minutes it was on. The booster only wears off by playing games that grand battlepoints.

Answer (score 0):

It counts only MATCH/GAME time (sitting in lobby or menu doesn't count for that), so if u activate it 10 minutes before the end of the match it will subtract the full game length anyway.